# cURL command line and send multiple request through the same connection?

Tags: web-services, perl, curl

I've to send too many request to a webservice. I can't send all the data in a big single request because of server limitations. I used to use cURL to do a POST request, but in this case cURL will set up and close a different connection for each sending.

Is there any way that cURL reuse a connection for multiple requests? Is there any alternative, e.g. wget, that could achieve this purpose?

I'd rather be able to avoid use a Perl homemade solution with `XML::Compile::WSDL11.`

Answer (score 0):

Enable HTTP/1.1 Keep-Alive. See [lwptut](http://p3rl.org/lwptut#Other-Browser-Attributes) and [LWP::ConnCache](http://p3rl.org/LWP%3a%3aConnCache).